# Why is running this function in a for loop faster on average than running it in parallel?

Tags: r, performance, matrix-multiplication

Amazon EC2 with 96 vCPU and 768 GB RAM. The for loop only needs roughly half the time per iteration compared to parSapply.

```
library(parallel)

mat <- matrix(rnorm(100*100), nrow = 100, ncol = 100)

theFunction <- function (x) {
  startTime <- proc.time()[3]
  for (i in 1:500){
    mat <- crossprod(mat,mat)
  }
  elapsedTime <- proc.time()[3] - startTime
  
  return(elapsedTime)
}

nTrials <- detectCores()
print(nTrials)
[1] 96

# 96 trials using for loop
elapsedTimeTotal <- 0
for (i in 1:nTrials){
  elapsedTimeTotal <- elapsedTimeTotal + theFunction(0)
}
elapsedTimeAverage <- elapsedTimeTotal / nTrials
print(elapsedTimeAverage)
[1] 0.4333125 

# 96 trials using parSapply
cl <- makeCluster(nTrials)
clusterExport(cl,"mat")
elapsedTimeAverage <- mean(parSapply(cl,1:nTrials,theFunction))
print(elapsedTimeAverage)
[1] 0.7999688
```

So 0.4333125 compared to 0.7999688. Why? My assumption was that those numbers would be equal unless there were memory issues. I've tried using fewer cores and it makes the difference smaller but never 0.

Comment: I'm not a parallel expert, but I suspect that the significant overhead of communicating with worker processes is playing a large role here: https://psu-psychology.github.io/r-bootcamp-2018/talks/parallel_r.html. Maybe if the function took longer to run then you'd see substantial improvement by parallelizing, but for quick computations like this it probably isn't worth the parallel effort.

Comment: Dubukay: The time for distributing data to and assembling data from the workers aren't included in the measurements, as the time is being measured inside of the function.